# How to get which offending source code and lines on C runtime?

Tags: c, pointers, runtime-error, static-analysis, dereference

I'm using this [code](https://github.com/kokizzu/kokizzu-benchmark/blob/master/assoc-small/uthash.c) and [uthash](https://troydhanson.github.io/uthash/) (`uthash-dev` in ubuntu)

```
// uthash.c
#include <string.h>  /* strcpy */
#include <stdlib.h>  /* malloc */
#include <stdio.h>   /* printf */
#include "uthash.h"

const int MAX_DATA = 1230000;

struct kv {
    char *key;
    double val;
    UT_hash_handle hh;
};

char i2ch[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'e', 'F'};

int get_first_digit(double d) {
    while(d > 10) {
        d /= 10;
    }
    return (int)(d);
}
char* to_rhex(int v) {
    char* hex = malloc(sizeof(char)*9); // because INT_MAX can be divided by 16 maximum 8 times
    memset(hex,0,9);
    int ctr = 0;
    do {
        hex[ctr++] = i2ch[v%16];
        v /= 16;
    } while(v > 0);
    return hex;
}

char* to_str(int v) {
    int len = snprintf(NULL,0,"%d",v);
    char *res = malloc(len+1);
    snprintf(res, len+1, "%d", v);  
    return res;
}

int set_or_inc(struct kv** m, char* key, int set, int inc, int *ctr) {
    struct kv* item = 0;
    HASH_FIND_STR(*m, key, item);
    if(!item) {
        item = malloc(sizeof(*item));
        item->key = key;
        item->val = (double)(set);
        HASH_ADD_KEYPTR(hh, *m, item->key, strlen(item->key), item) ;
        return 0;
    } else {
        item->val += (double)(inc);
        *ctr += 1;
        return 1; // key not used
    }
}
int main() {
    struct kv *m = NULL;
    int dup1 =0, dup2 =0, dup3 =0;
    for(int z = MAX_DATA; z > 0; z--) {
        int val2 = MAX_DATA - z;
        int val3 = MAX_DATA*2 - z;
        char *key1 = to_str(z);
        char *key2 = to_str(val2);
        char *key3 = to_rhex(val3);
        if(set_or_inc(&m, key1, z, val2, &dup1)) free(key1);
        if(set_or_inc(&m, key2, val2, val3, &dup2)) free(key2);
        if(set_or_inc(&m, key3, val3, z, &dup3)) free(key3);
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n",dup1, dup2, dup3);
    int total = 0, verify = 0, count = 0;
    struct kv *tmp, *item;
    HASH_ITER(hh, m, item, tmp) {
        total += get_first_digit(item->val);
        verify += strlen(item->key);
        count += 1;
        HASH_DEL(m,item);
        free(item->key);
        free(item);
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n",total, verify, count);
}
```

when using tcc with bound check:

```
time tcc -b -g -run uthash.c
bcheck.c __bound_ptr_indir8: 0x7fff3cd67ec8 is outside of the region
Runtime error: dereferencing invalid pointer
at 0x5626cfebe9b5 set_or_inc()
by 0x5626cfec15e9 main()
Command exited with non-zero status 255

CPU: 0.00s      Real: 0.00s     RAM: 3480KB
```

direct running (no problem when checked with `valgrind -s --track-origins=yes --keep-stacktraces=alloc-and-free`):

```
time tcc -run uthash.c
637912 641149 67002
3808703 14182513 2343937
Command exited with non-zero status 25

CPU: 2.52s      Real: 2.60s     RAM: 292144KB
```

when using gcc (also no runtime error when using `-fstack-protector-all` flag):

```
gcc uthash.c && time ./a.out
637912 641149 67002
3808703 14182513 2343937

CPU: 2.47s      Real: 2.57s     RAM: 290492KB
```

when using clang (also no runtime error when using `-fsanitize=address` flag):

```
clang uthash.c && time ./a.out
637912 641149 67002
3808703 14182513 2343937

CPU: 2.50s      Real: 2.59s     RAM: 290448KB
```

Only when using `tcc` it shows that error on runtime, how could I know which line number is the cause?

Comment: Note: `to_rhex(0)` returns `""`, not `"0"`.  Use `do {} while();`.  `to_rhex(some_negative)` --> `""`.

Comment: nice one, thanks @Reinstate, updated